# How to perform batch update with Map<String,String> using JdbcTemplate in Spring JDBC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hashmap, spring-jdbc

I have a bean which has two fields
1: `Map<String,String> client`
2: `String target`

I have to write this bean to the database.
I have a query `"INSERT INTO my_table(client_key ,client_value ,target) VALUES(?,?,?)"`

So every key-value pair and the String target should be inserted into the table.

How do I go about doing this efficiently ? The batch update documentation only show to write with lists.

Edit:
Here's what I have tried so far.

This is my bean class:

```
public class FinalBean {
   
    private Map<String,String> client;
    private String target;
    
    public Map<String, String> getClient() {
        return client;
    }
    public void setClient(Map<String, String> client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
    public String getTarget() {
        return target;
    }
    public void setTarget(String target) {
        this.target = target;
    } 
    
    
}
```

This is how I attempted to write the bean.

```
public void saveFinalBean(final FinalBean bean)
    {
        
        String insert_query="INSERT INTO my_table(client_key ,client_value ,target) VALUES(?,?,?)";
        
        final List< Entry<String,String> > list= getMapAsEntryList(bean.getClient());
        
        int[] updateCounts = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(insert_query,
                new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                     
                    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                        Entry<String,String> entry = list.get(i);
                        ps.setString(1, entry.getKey());
                        ps.setString(2, entry.getValue());
                        ps.setString(3, bean.getTarget());
                    }
                     
                   
                    public int getBatchSize() {
                        return list.size();
                    }
                });
        
    }


 private List<Entry<String,String>> getMapAsEntryList(Map<String, String> client) {
            List<Entry<String,String>> result=new ArrayList<Entry<String,String>>();
            
             
             for(Entry<String,String> entry : client.entrySet())
             {
                 result.add(entry);
             }
            
            return result;
        
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? did you explore `batch` operations in `jdbcTemplate`?

Comment: Yes I went through the documentation of batch operations , but they only specify how to write lists using the batchUpdate method and implementing methods from BatchPreparedStatementSetter interface. My problem is how do I write the map's each key-value pair along with the String target. I could convert everything to a list and then try , but I was wondering if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: write down some minimal code here ,will guide you.  lots of approach are there. its hard to explain without code.

Comment: @priyranjan I have added what I have tried. Please take a look once